# Apple watch solar dial glitch

Tags: apple-watch

As you can see the time is 10:19pm or 22:19, which is night. This watch face has the day and night flipped. How to fix that?

[image]

Comment: Has this gotten sorted with a software update?

Comment: Nope, it works only when the location service is on. It does not work if you changed the location to the country you want. The problem also exist in the Apple watch simulator in the XCode, I couldn't change the country there.

Comment: Well, if location service is on and you still have this bug, apple will have to fix the code. If you are faking the location or not enabling accurate location, the code just might not have contemplated it and they assumed or require accurate location services.

Comment: In Xcode, location service was on and I still have this bug.
In the watch, If location service is on, everything goes okey.

Comment: So you have a bug in Xcode simulator only and want to fix that?

Comment: My main problem is solved by the accepted answer, Xcode was a side note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the paird iPhone go to "Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services" and be sure you allow  "While Using the App" for Apple Watch faces.

You probably have this turned off so the Watch doesn't know the correct display for the day/night.

[image]

Comment: I did that, nothing happed.

Comment: My location is Egypt, could you try to reallocate yours to Egypt and see if you have the day and night filpped?

Comment: Change the setting to 'Never', exit out, go back in, change it to 'While using the app' and reboot both devices.  If that doesn't fix it, can you add screenshots of your Location settings on your Watch and iPhone to verify these are set correctly?